# Convert a .jpg image to rgb in micropython?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to create a program on the Raspberry Pi Pico W that downloads a jpg image and displays a very pixilated version of the image on an addressable led matrix. I have decided to attempt to use micro python as my coding language for this project since I have already completed a similar project in the full python language. Since I am downloading the images from an online source I am stuck using the '.jpg' format at a fixed size.

I have been running into some difficulties processing the image. To run on the addressable LEDs (Neopixel) I want to collect the rgb data from each individual pixel of the .jpg and add them to a list.

Working on python I know that the PIL/Pillow library is a great solution to this problem.

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('256256.jpg',formats=None)
print(image)
from numpy import asarray
data = asarray(image)
```

Unfortunately the RP2040 doesn't seem have enough storage space to handle the module.
I need to find a way to decode the image using the modules readily available to micro python.
I have attempted to reverse engineer the PIL open feature but haven't had any luck so far.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I only know two ways to open a jpeg in Python. If Pillow won't fit then you sure won't be able to use OpenCV.

Comment: As the Pico W has wifi and you are grabbing a JPEG from the Net, maybe you could use a Web API/service to downsize the JPEG and turn it into a NetPBM/PPM format image that you can read on a Pico W very simply without any extra packages and without filling the memory.

Comment: I've previously looked into APIs to resize images but wasn't a huge fan of having to signup/depend on another service. Ultimately I do agree that it might be my only reasonable option. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a Raspberry Pi at home with a little Python image resizing and conversion to PPM service written with Python's built-in http simple server or some Flask...

Comment: think I'd also recommend going the route of having another box/VM to do the image conversion.  that said, there are small libraries (e.g. https://github.com/Bodmer/TJpg_Decoder) that you might be able to wrap to get working on the RP2040.

Comment: Or an $8 Raspberry Pi Zero as a an attached *"co-processor"*... or even replacing the Pico.

Comment: A quick web search found me [this page](https://yasoob.me/posts/understanding-and-writing-jpeg-decoder-in-python/) that shows how to decode JPEG in pure Python. I haven't tried it out though, either on desktop or MicroPython.